# Create a bar chart with proportions

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar chart from data that looks similar to this:

| bird | dr | season |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ambi | 45 | molting |
| ambi | 45 | molting |
| ambi | 45 | molting |
| ambi | 45 | breeding |
| ambi | 45 | breeding |
| ambi | 45 | winter |
| ambi | 45 | winter |
| abum | 60 | molting |
| abum | 60 | molting |
| abum | 60 | molting |
| abum | 60 | breeding |
| abum | 60 | breeding |
| abum | 60 | winter |
| abum | 60 | winter |

I would like all birds listed on the y axis, and I would like the x axis to be dr. I would like the bars to be colored-coded based on proportion of observations from each season. For example, for abum, I would like the bar to reach 0.6, and I would like the bar to be color-coded based on season. abum has 3/7 observations during the molting season, 2/7 during breeding, and 2/7 during winter. I would like the colors in the bar to reflect this. This is the code I have so far:

```
plot <- ggplot(data=test, aes(x=dr, y=bird, fill=season)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity")+
     scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
     theme_minimal()
```

This sets up my birds correctly on the y axis and color codes the bars, but I think it is using some kind of count value as opposed to the dr value on the x axis.

An image of what the code is producing:
[image: plot image]

The x axis does not reflect the dr values. I am not sure where the x axis values are coming from. I would also like to reverse the order of the birds, so that they are in alphabetical order from top to bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about `dr` part. If there's something wrong, please let me know.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

test %>%
  group_by(bird, season) %>%
  summarise(key = unique(dr),
            dr = sum(dr)) %>%
  group_by(bird) %>%
  mutate(dr = dr/sum(dr) * key/100) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(bird = fct_reorder(bird, desc(bird))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=bird, y=dr, fill=season)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]